# React Native width on tablet

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have created a new react-native app

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
```

and added the code found here:

[medium link](https://medium.com/soluto-engineering/size-matters-5aeeb462900a)

The app looks like this on the iPad simulator:

[imgur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jwmX.jpg)

How can I set it to full width?

Comment: it seems your code is correct, rebuild your project or use another method like flex:1

Answer (score 0):

remove the `width` & `height` properties from your `container` style and add `flex: 1`